# Classification of subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Tags: group-theory

Fix an  integer $n\geq 2$, can we list all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$?

Comment: You could list the matrices with $n$ columns in (row) Hermite Normal Form. There is a $1-1$ correspondence between such matrices and subgroups of ${\mathbb Z}^n$, where a canonical set of generators of the subgroup is specified by the corresponding matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to subgroup growth, see for example [Lubotzki's article](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~nbrady/teaching/s11-5863/lubotzky.pdf). The subgroups are counted (or listed) according to their index in the group. The Zeta function of groups plays a role to describe the asymptotic growth. This is computed for $\mathbb{Z}^n$ in Theorem $2.1$. Denote by $s_n(G)$ the number of subgroups of index $\le n$ in $G$. Then
$s_n(\mathbb{Z}^2)\sim \frac{\pi^2}{12}n^2$ for $n\to \infty$. In general,
$$
s_n(\mathbb{Z^d)}\sim\frac{\zeta(d)\zeta(d-1)\cdots \zeta(2)}{d}n^d
$$
for $n\to \infty$. Here $\zeta$ denotes the classical Riemann Zeta function.

Comment: Thanks.Is there any results for subgroups of infinite index?

Comment: The asymptotic is for $n\to \infty$, $n$ being the index.